# Filter values no selected

Tags: powerbi

I’m trying with no results to filter values not selected. For example, I have a column with 10 elements. In a slicer I select 2 of them, so I want to view in a table below the values not selected.

Example:

Group
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
J

If I filter A, D and G, I want to see in the table:

B
C
E
F
H
I
J

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do that, but it's possible.
First, create a new table **without** relationship, where you put slicerColumn (in my example 'Table 2'[Column1]). Create slicer based on this new table, then create a measure like this one:

```
Break = CALCULATE( COUNTROWS('Table'), FILTER('Table', not('Table'[Column1] in 
VALUES('Table 2'[Column1]))))
```

[image]